# unable reconnect to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

Trying to stop Postgresql queries, I followed this thread:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/547434/how-to-nicely-stop-all-postgres-processes
where at some point say:

```sql
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE datname = 'YOUR_NAME';
```

Executed, then I cannot reconnect nor via psql nor pgAdmin

```
ERROR: psql: FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
```

Tried:

`sudo service postgresql start` (and stop, restart, etc) without success

And... using htop on command line, I see all postgres processes I wanted to stop, they still are running!

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to stop a single query, or if you want to shutdown the Postgres service alltogether. The first query will kill all **sessions** (=connections) to a specific database. It does not cancel one specific running query.

Comment: thanks, but doesn't 
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(<pid of the process>)
stop a process/sql query? I used to use it via pgAdmin, even if not always worked, but sometimes it did...